# Evaluation of the indefinite integral $\int \frac{\operatorname{sech}^2(x)}{ \operatorname{sech} ^2(x)+1} \,dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}$I have simplied $$\int \frac{\sech^2(x)}{ \sech ^2(x)+1} \, dx$$ to $$\int\frac 2 {\cosh(2x)+3} \,dx$$ and am wondering if this is the most efficient way of answering the question and where to go from here.

Comment: and then 
$$\int{\frac{2}{ \cosh(2x)+3}dx}=\int{\frac{2}{ \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}+3}dx}=\int\dfrac{2dz}{z^2+6z+1}$$
with $z=e^{2x}$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

using the substitution
$$t=\tanh (x) $$
with
$$dt=(1-t^2)dx $$
and
$$\cosh(2x)=\frac {1+t^2}{1-t^2} $$

the integrale becomes
$$\int \frac {dt}{2-t^2} $$
to finish, put $t=u\sqrt {2} $ and observe that
$$\frac{2}{1-u^2}=\frac {1}{1-u}+\frac {1}{1+u} $$

Comment: How does $\cosh(2x)=\frac {1+t^2}{1-t^2}$ ?

Comment: @randb See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution end of page!

Comment: $1-th^2(x)=1/cosh^2(x). $and $cosh (2x)+1=2cosh^2 (x) $